# Filter the elements according to another value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to output the number of all questions for each post in ReactJs. 
For this i created the next code:

```js
const posts = [{
        title: 1,
        id: "123"
    },
    {
        title: 2,
        id: "1234"
    },
    {
        title: 3,
        id: "12345"
    }
]

const questions = [{
        id: 55,
        name: 'question one',
        id_post: '123'
    },
    {
        id: 56,
        name: 'question two',
        id_post: '123'
    },
    {
        id: 57,
        name: 'question three',
        id_post: '1234'
    },
    {
        id: 58,
        name: 'question four',
        id_post: '123'
    },

];

posts.map( (e, k) => {
    return (
      <Link key={k} to={`demo/${e.id}/url`}>
      { questions.filter(here i want to output the number of questions that correspond to each post)}
      </Link>
    )
})
```

I have `posts` array and `questions` array. I want to create a `Link` with it own id in the url and in the same time to filter the number of questions for each post, and inside the`Link` to output the number. How to do to this?

...the issue is next: I am using ant design, table component, and there  i can use the next structure:

```
`  render: ()=>(
    console.log('render'),
    events.map( (e, key) => {
      console.log(ev.id);
        return (
            <Link key={k} to={`demo/${e.id}/url`}>
            { questions.filter(q => q.id_post === e.id).length }
            </Link>
        )
      )
    })
```

`I use this to create a column in my table. The problem is that i have to many renders. When i put this code i get all ids in`console.log(ev.id)`on each render. And at the end i get for example not`0`as length but`00000000`, depending but how many renders, or ids i have. How to solve this? Please, take a look at the line: 45 https://codesandbox.io/s/8i1dy

Comment: Your ids are strings in `posts` and integers in `questions`, is that correct or you can modify any of those?

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava, i corrected. Both ids are string.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is doing this count beforehand:

```
const questionCountByPost = questions.reduce((acc, q) => {
  const postId = q.id_post;
  acc[postId] = (acc[postId] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

... which looks like a nice thing to do each time either your posts or questions change. You can use this object inside your map function like this:

```
return (
  <Link key={k} to={`demo/${e.id}/url`}>
  { questionCountByPost[e.id] }
  </Link>
)
```

---

Another approach is doing this count directly in template:

```
return (
  <Link key={k} to={`demo/${e.id}/url`}>
  { questions.filter(q => q.id_post === e.id).length }
  </Link>
)
```

It's less performant (as you'll have to iterate through the whole array each time), but apparently more readable. If the number of posts and questions is not that big, it might a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const posts = [{
        title: 1,
        id: "123"
    },
    {
        title: 2,
        id: "1234"
    },
    {
        title: 3,
        id: "12345"
    }
]

const questions = [{
        id: 55,
        name: 'question one',
        id_post: 123
    },
    {
        id: 56,
        name: 'question two',
        id_post: 123
    },
    {
        id: 57,
        name: 'question three',
        id_post: 1234
    },
    {
        id: 58,
        name: 'question four',
        id_post: 123
    },

];


posts.map(({id}) => {
  let count = 0
  console.log(questions.filter(({id_post}) => (id_post == id)).length)
  
})
```

Comment: You could use `filter` + `Array.length`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava yes that is also an option.