# Using .filter in reactjs to output the length of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I created an app that should output the length of the questions related to posts. Basically I should get the length of all questions for every post. But now I get just `0000`. How to solve this?

The link of my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-ant-design-demo-4tl5h

Why I get too many renders here?

```js
{
    title: "Questions",
    key: "questions",
    render: () =>
      // console.log('render'),
      posts.map((e, key) => {
        console.log(e.id);
        return (
          <Router>
            <Link key={key} to={`demo/${e.id}/url`}>
              {questions !== undefined
                ? questions.filter(q => q.id_post === e.id).length
                : 0}
            </Link>
          </Router>
        );
      })
  }
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter the elements according to another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827308/filter-the-elements-according-to-another-value)

Answer (score 1):

One is `Number`, another is `String`, it's not equal if you use `===`

Fix it by adding a Number() or a toString()

```
questions.filter(q => q.id_post === Number(e.id)).length
// or
questions.filter(q => q.id_post.toString() === e.id).length
```

Or just change your data source to make it the same type

---

#### Update

Fix the incorrect number: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60829482/11872246

Comment: i changed the code, but i get length: `310` for each post. Could you take a look?

Comment: what do you think?