# React Ant table customized column calculation. How to get the length of other items in each row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, antd

I made an application where I output the length of the questions for each post, but I get the result for each post equal with: `310`.

Probably it happens because of too many renders.
How to solve this and get the real length of the questions for each post?

link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-ant-design-demo-4tl5h

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter the elements according to another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827308/filter-the-elements-according-to-another-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the incorrect number: do not push, use callback event of **render** instead

Ant Table API: [table Column](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column)

```
const App = () => {
  const res = [
    ...Object.keys(posts[0]).map(i => {
      return {
        title: i,
        dataIndex: i,
        key: i
      };
    }),
    {
      title: "Questions",
      key: "Questions",
      render: e => {
        console.log(e); // Object {title: 1, id: "123"}
        return (
          <Router>
            <Link to={`demo/${e.id}/url`}>
              {questions.filter(q => q.id_post.toString() === e.id).length}
            </Link>
          </Router>
        );
      }
    }
  ];
  return <Table columns={res} dataSource={posts} />;
};
```

[image]

[image: Edit Basic Usage - Ant Design Demo]

Comment: @Asking Could you be more specific? The online demo seems normal